# Memory swapping or file writing/reading

Tags: c++, optimization

MY question is simple (I guess)!
If I have an huge amount of memory to allocate for any reason (let's say I want to load a really big point cloud in memory and apply filter on it in order to reduce it and then save it again), but my computer doesn't have sufficient memory to open it entirely, so it will use memory swapping.

What would be the faster way to do it :
 - Use memory swapping, and let the computer do its things.
 - Use a file-based octree (I create file that will contains my points).. For example, I read X points, and rewrite them in the file corresponding, then reread X points, and do it until my big file of points is read entirely. Then I apply the filter on each octree-file-leaf, and then rewrite them 1 by 1 in the big file.

Is there any way to answer this question?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a thrid option, consider [memory mapped file IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). It allows you to access a file as if it was fully loaded into (virtual) memory but allows the OS to load and unload parts of the file as needed; you may want to make sure to have the file mapped as read-only so that the OS knows that it will not have to deal with writing back dirty pages.

Comment: Oh! Yes! Memory mapping! it get out of my mind! It is probably the best way! Thanks for the remainder!!

Comment: Your second approch will be likely to be much better(performance wise). In my personal experience the memory mapped IO with hugefiles always performed worse.

Comment: In my case, The memory mapped would only takes part after having read the big file, because I have to read the big file with a library that does not allows me the memory mapping. So I could create a mix of second and third options

Answer (score 1):

As a thrid option, consider [memory mapped file IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). It allows you to access a file as if it was fully loaded into (virtual) memory but allows the OS to load and unload parts of the file as it sees fit, applying all the smart caching strategies (LRU, prefetching, balancing caching vs. paging, ...) it has; you may want to make sure to have the file mapped as read-only so that the OS knows that it will not have to deal with writing back dirty pages.

If some kind of index structure (octree or whatever) is beneficial or not heavily depends on the kind of queries you will do and on the IO performance of the file system.